# How to update nested cloudformation stack in AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Within my AWS Amplify application I started receiving emails about Node.js 8.10 end-of-life, urging me to change to Node.js 10.x.

I was able to change versions of functions that I've created by `amplify add function` by simply editing generated cloudformation template. However, when I tried doing so for resources that Amplify generated for me, I got **No Change** upon running `amplify status`.

To be more specific, the function that I'm unable to change is located in `nested-cloudformation-stack.yml` (within `amplify/backend/awscloudformation/`). The function is called `UpdateRolesWithIDPFunction`, which presumably has something to do with Cognito setup.

Currently I'm running on `3.17` of `amplify-cli`.

How can I update that function to Node.js 10.x?

Answer (score 0):

A year later this is still happening with their generic amplify install. Only difference is that it is now saying use nodejs12, but like you, I run into the same problem where the amplify push command modifies the node version and hence never pushes.